# How can I make Read Only Attribute to a row of table conditionally

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core

I am trying to make the  All TD element of the row read-only attribute  depends the value of the column in the model. Here is the details given below. If the model.IsProtected value is true , then all Td element of the row must read-only attribute. That should be protected from editing . Please help with suggested code

model class

```
EmployeeModel
IsProtected boolean
EmployeeName string
Salary decimal
Bonus decimal
```

```html
@Model List<EmployeeModel>
for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
<td>
      <input asp-for="@Model.IsProtected" type="hidden" />
</td>
<td>@Model.EmployeeName</td>
<td>
         <div >
                <input type="number" placeholder="0.00" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:central" class="form-control format-text" asp-for="@Model.Salary" />
 </div>
</td>
<td>
<div >
<input type="number" placeholder="0.00" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:central" class="form-control format-text" asp-for="@Model.Bonus" />
</div>
</td>
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use ternary conditional operator `?:` like below:

```
@model List<EmployeeModel>
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
<td>
    <input asp-for="@Model[i].IsProtected" type="hidden" />
</td>
<td>@Model[i].EmployeeName</td>
<td>
    <div>
        <input type="number" placeholder="0.00" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:central" class="form-control format-text" 
               asp-for="@Model[i].Salary" readonly="@(Model[i].IsProtected ? "readonly" : null )"/>
    </div>
</td>
<td>
    <div>
        <input type="number" placeholder="0.00" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:central" class="form-control format-text" 
               asp-for="@Model[i].Bonus" readonly="@(Model[i].IsProtected ? "readonly" : null )"/>
    </div>
</td>
}
```